# How to change a link into a span of text or some kind of non-anchored element with prototype

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs

I have a link:

```
<a id="theLink" href="h***://stackoverflow.com">Go to SO</a>
```

How can I use prototype to either strip `<a>`'s or just leave the innerHTML so that the elements becomes:

`[h***://stackoverflow.com]`  (something that is no longer clickable)?

Or maybe convert the `<a>` to a `<span>`

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
function removeAnchor() {
        var link = document.getElementById('theLink');
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        var txt = link.href;
        var textNode= document.createTextNode(txt);
        span.appendChild(textNode);
        link.parentNode.replaceChild(span, link);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To replace the `<a>` with a `<span>` with the initial element's href as content:

```
$('theLink').replace((new Element('span')).update($('theLink').href));
```

The result will be:

```
<span>h***://stackoverflow.com</span>
```

To replace the  with a  with the same content:

```
$('theLink').replace((new Element('span')).update($('theLink').innerHTML));
```

Which will result:

```
<span>Go to SO</span>
```

Comment: i think he want something pure javascript (without jquery)

Comment: He said "How can I use prototype...". He means the Prototype JavaScript framework, and that's what my example uses.