# Disable link in UIWebView in appearance and function

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4

I wish to disable the href links on a UIWebView. First, I want the look of the link to change so the user doesn't think it is clickable. Second, I want the actual link to not be able to be tapped. I do not want to try `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` since that not change the appearance of my links.

I found this answer:
[Disabling visible links in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219802/disabling-visible-links-in-uiwebview/4510198#4510198)

But the above hasn't worked for me. This is my code:

```
NSString* s=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"for (a in document.getElementsByTagName(\"a\")) {a.href = \"\";}"];
[myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:s];
```

I've been working on this for hours, any suggestions are appreciated! Thanks!

UPDATE:

I tried the following javascript but it is still not working

```
for(link in document.getElementsByTagName("a")) {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        var txt = link.href;
        var textNode= document.createTextNode(txt);
        span.appendChild(textNode);
        if(link!=undefined){
            link.parentNode.replaceChild(span, link);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code provided would only keep the link from having a destination, but it would still look like a link.

I would use the same concept, but use the javascript from  this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678086/how-to-change-a-link-into-a-span-of-text-or-some-kind-of-non-anchored-element-wit), which basically turns the href into a span so it just appears as text.

Comment: Thanks! Hmm.. I tried the following but it didn't work:  for(link in document.getElementsByTagName("a")) {
        var span = document.createElement("span");
        var txt = link.href;
        var textNode= document.createTextNode(txt);
        span.appendChild(textNode);
        if(link!=undefined){
            link.parentNode.replaceChild(span, link);
        }
}